# Get access to an image view from ListFragment

Tags: android, android-widget, android-fragments

I have a ListFragment with its Layout A and for each item on the list I have its layout as well called B. Inside B I have an image view with id "imgVi":

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgVi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

From my ListFragment in the method onCreateView I want to get access to this ImageView for change the image src. How can I do this?. Since this imageView is not in the ListFragment layout, I cant do this:

```
ImageView imgEmp = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewEmp);
imgEmp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_emp_selected);
```

But layout B is in layout A. Because its a list with its rows.

Any help will be apreciated. I'm new with Android.

EDITED: I got it work, just follow this tutorial http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/

```
public class ListClientsCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

private Context context;
private int layout;

public ListClientsCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {

    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);

    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    Cursor c = getCursor();

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

    int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex("name");
    String name = c.getString(nombreCol);

    int telfCol = c.getColumnIndex("telf");
    String telf = c.getString(telfCol);

    /**
     * Next set the name of the entry.
     */    

    TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewNombEmp);
    if (name_text != null) {
        name_text .setText(name);
    }

    TextView telf_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewTelfEmp);
    if (telf_text != null) {
        telf_text.setText(telf);
    }

    ImageView imgEmp = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewEmp);
    if (imgEmp != null) {
        imgEmp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_tab_emp_selected);
    }

    return v;
}


}
```

And then in my onCreateView of the ListFragment I call:

```
ListClientCursorAdapter notes = new ListClientCursorAdapter(context,R.layout.activity_fil_client, mCursor, from, to, 0);
setListAdapter(notes);
```

Instead of SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: I didn't quite understand. So B is the layout for each row of your List. right? it means you have 0 or more (depending on number of items on the list) of these imageviews? If that's the case you should access that imageview inside the adapter not in your onCreateView method!!

Comment: yes, thats right. I'll an image view for each row. Can you provide me any example of that?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `ListFragment`, you will have to set an adapter for the list. Inside that adapter, you can override the method `getView()`, and you can access the `ImageView` there, you can't access it from the `onCreateView` method inside the fragment.

Comment: Is that a custom adapter?. Where should I define it?. Can I override the getView method in my ListFragment class?

Comment: You can override getView() method in the custom adapter, not inside the fragment.